# Laravel 8 query json data from database

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, laravel

I have a column name test in which I am storing a JSON data and the data is like this

```
{
    "id": 4030662213806,
    "buyer_accepts_marketing": true,
    "cancel_reason": null,
    "cancelled_at": null,
    "line_items": [
        {
            "id": 10357822685358,
            "vendor": "Samsung-1",
        },
        {
            "id": 10357822685358,
            "vendor": "Samsung-2",
        },
        {
            "id": 10357822685358,
            "vendor": "Samsung-3",
        }
    ],
    
}
```

I am trying to get data where vendor value is Samsung-1

and my query is like this

```
$query = Test::where('id','4030662213806')
$query->orWhereJsonContains('test->line_items->vendor',$val);
```

also tried

```
$query->orWhereJsonContains('test->line_items->vendor',$val);
```

But didn't work

Any help please

Comment: I think you do not need a `test` on there. `line_items->vendor`

Comment: As you can see line_items is an array so will only line_items->vendor work ? I also tried like 
line_items[0]->vendor
line_items[1]->vendor

Comment: According to your code the `test` is your table name but you say you have also a column named `test` I think you have a mistake here.

Comment: Ok lets assume table name is Order I added test only for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query where `line_items` array contains the key `vendor` and value `Samsung-1`

```
$query->orWhereJsonContains('test->line_items', ['vendor' => $val]);
```

Also if you are trying to query `id` from the `test` JSON column the first line should be

```
$query = Test::where('test->id', 4030662213806);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$query = Test::where('id','10357822685358')
$query->orWhereJsonContains('test->line_items->vendor',$val);
```

Because it's id and value samsung 1

Comment: The first Test::where is just an example its the actual query  I want to know is the condition in the orWhereJsonContains